# Language level in CV using moderncv class

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am trying to create my CV using `moderncv` class. In the languages section, I want it to be as the following image:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve that using  `moderncv` class?

Note: I used [this example](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/physics/vnrpxccpnqkw#.W3nkGegzY2x) to create my CV.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')


\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...



\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{First Name}{Last Name}
%\title{Computer Science}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{City}{Country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+5555555555555}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{email@hotmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\small{Undergraduate UBC student completing a physics major with a biology minor. Passionate about science, philosophy and engineering with strong interpersonal skills and autodidactic tendencies.}



\section{Achievements}



\section{Education}


        \vspace{2pt}

\section{Technical and Personal skills}


\section{Languages}

        \vspace{6pt}
         \begin{itemize}

            \item{\textbf{Arabic}} %Five out of five
            \vspace{6pt}
            \item{\textbf{English} } %Four out of five

         \end{itemize}







\section{References}

        \vspace{6pt}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item{One }

            \vspace{6pt}

            \item{Two}

        \end{itemize}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I provided the link of the source code that I used, however I edited the question and added a MWE. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `\item` doesn't take an argument. `\item{\textbf{Foo}}` is the same as `\textbf{Foo}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a minimal working example (yet), the following takes a language and a number (ranging from 0 to 5) and outputs the language and your 5 dots.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{languagecolor}{red}
\colorlet{nolanguagecolor}{gray}
\newcount\languagecount
\newcommand\languageknowledge[2]
  {%
    \hbox
      {%
        \makebox[4cm][l]{#1}%
        \languagecount=0
        \loop\ifnum\languagecount<#2
          \advance\languagecount1
          \textcolor{languagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
        \repeat
        \loop\ifnum\languagecount<5
          \advance\languagecount1
          \textcolor{nolanguagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
        \repeat
      }%
  }

\begin{document}
\languageknowledge{German}{5}
\languageknowledge{English}{4}
\languageknowledge{French}{0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** embedding the answer in your style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{First Name}{Last Name}
%\title{Computer Science} % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{City}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{+5555555555555}
\email{email@hotmail.com}

% setting the colours according to \moderncvcolor
\colorlet{languagecolor}{color1}
\colorlet{nolanguagecolor}{color2}
\newcount\languagecount
\newcommand\languageknowledge[2]
  {%
    % if you change the 4cm you can change the distance, the 4cm is the space
    % reserved for the language's name, immediately after it the dots are
    % printed.
    \makebox[4cm][l]{\textbf{#1}}%
    %\hfill % if you want the dots to be at the right margin
    \languagecount=0
    \loop\ifnum\languagecount<#2
      \advance\languagecount1
      \textcolor{languagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
    \repeat
    \loop\ifnum\languagecount<5
      \advance\languagecount1
      \textcolor{nolanguagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
    \repeat
  }

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\small{Undergraduate UBC student completing a physics major with a biology minor. Passionate about science, philosophy and engineering with strong interpersonal skills and autodidactic tendencies.}
\section{Achievements}
\section{Education}
        \vspace{2pt}
\section{Technical and Personal skills}
\section{Languages}

        \vspace{6pt}
         \begin{itemize}

           \item \languageknowledge{Arabic}{5} %Five out of five
            %\vspace{6pt}
            \item \languageknowledge{English}{4} %Four out of five

         \end{itemize}
\section{References}

        \vspace{6pt}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item{One }

            \vspace{6pt}

            \item{Two}

        \end{itemize}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I provided the link of the source code that I used, however I edited the question and added a MWE. Thank you very much for your answer.