# ModernCV Resume Language Level adjustments

Tags: moderncv, cv

Does anyone know how I can adjust the size and spacing of the circles to provide the language level in my modern CV template

For MWE please refer to:

[Language Level in modern CV / Texexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446739/language-level-in-cv-using-moderncv-class)

Thanks for your help. 
Best Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the two elements you want to change need to be changed within the `\languageknowledge` macro. As you can see I added a `\LARGE%` in there, but this could theoretically be any font size for the bullets. Below you can then see `\hspace{1em}%` which is the inter-bullet-spacing if you will.

This results in bigger bullets with a wider spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{First Name}{Last Name}
%\title{Computer Science} % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{City}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{+5555555555555}
\email{email@hotmail.com}

% setting the colours according to \moderncvcolor
\colorlet{languagecolor}{color1}
\colorlet{nolanguagecolor}{color2}
\newcount\languagecount
\newcommand\languageknowledge[2]
  {%
    % if you change the 4cm you can change the distance, the 4cm is the space
    % reserved for the language's name, immediately after it the dots are
    % printed.
    \makebox[4cm][l]{\textbf{#1}}%
    %\hfill % if you want the dots to be at the right margin
    {\LARGE%
    \languagecount=0
    \loop\ifnum\languagecount<#2
      \advance\languagecount1
      \textcolor{languagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
      \hspace{1em}%
    \repeat
    \loop\ifnum\languagecount<5
      \advance\languagecount1
      \textcolor{nolanguagecolor}{$\bullet$}%
      \hspace{1em}%
    \repeat}
  }

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\small{Undergraduate UBC student completing a physics major with a biology minor. Passionate about science, philosophy and engineering with strong interpersonal skills and autodidactic tendencies.}
\section{Achievements}
\section{Education}
        \vspace{2pt}
\section{Technical and Personal skills}
\section{Languages}

        \vspace{6pt}
         \begin{itemize}

           \item \languageknowledge{Arabic}{5} %Five out of five
            %\vspace{6pt}
            \item \languageknowledge{English}{4} %Four out of five

         \end{itemize}
\section{References}

        \vspace{6pt}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item{One }

            \vspace{6pt}

            \item{Two}

        \end{itemize}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastian, thank you! If you like the answer, please upvote it and accept it by clicking on the gray checkmark left to it, which afterwards turns green. This is the way to show you found an answer valueable and it solved your problem on StackExchange. Thank you!